# COMException: Cannot change thread mode after it is set on EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null) C#

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, com, webview2

I am writing a C# application that will be loading a technical chart webpage that is generated by an outside server API. I am just trying to display a webpage that i would like to be loaded in a custom panel using WebView2 (as original WebBrowser is deprecated, and Cef has x64 problems).

However, the following code fails to execute properly and is throwing a com exception, when  attempting to initialize the custom view:

```
class ChartView : Panel
    {
#nullable enable
        private string? chartViewFileAddr { get; set; }
#nullable disable

        private WebView2 chartWebView { get; set; }

        private async void ensureWeb2Init() => await chartWebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
        private bool isInit = false;

        public ChartView(string? chartViewFileAddr) : base()
        {
            this.chartViewFileAddr= chartViewFileAddr ?? "";
            this.BorderStyle =  BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 500);
            this.Location = new Point(0, 320);
            this.Name = "ChartWebView";
            chartWebView= new WebView2();
            chartWebView.Size = this.Size;
            chartWebView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            if (isInit == false)
            {
                Task.Run(() => this.ensureWeb2Init()).Wait();
                isInit = true;
            }
            chartWebView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("google.com"); //base address for testing
            this.Controls.Add(chartWebView);
        }

    }
```

When it runs, it fails on calling ensureWeb2Init. If i attempt to run the task without the Wait function, it fails to run asynchronously, if i add the wait function, the async task throws the following:

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Cannot change thread mode after it is set. (0x80010106 (RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE))'**

For whatever reason, i cannot get the WebView2 to initialize properly. Is there anything i am doing wrong here? thank you for your help.

Comment: As noted in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.ensurecorewebview2async?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1462.37), you get an exception "if the calling thread isn't the thread which created this object (usually the UI thread)". You are calling it from a threadpool thread, which is not the thread that created the chartWebView. (Furthermore, you are calling `chartWebView.CoreWebView2.Navigate()` without checking whether initialization is complete.

Comment: Set the WebView2.Source, which initializes the control. Or expose an async Task method to do the initialization and await call it when you need it. Or call the method like a normal method, and do rest of the things in CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem:** As mentioned in the comments and the other answer, the issue is calling the method in a thread other than the UI thread. According to [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.ensurecorewebview2async?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1462.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235):

> Note that even though this method is asynchronous and returns a Task, it still must be called on the UI thread like most public
> functionality of most UI controls.

> InvalidOperationException Thrown if this instance of CoreWebView2 is already disposed, or if the calling thread isn't the thread which
> created this object (usually the UI thread).

**Solutions:** You may want to consider either of the following solutions based on your requirements:

- **Set the Source property, instead of calling EnsureCoreWebView2Async**

  You can set the [WebView2.Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.source?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1462.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property, which will initialize the CoreWebView2 implicitly if it's not already initialized. Then you don't need to call `EnsureCoreWebView2Async`. For example:

  ```
   webView21.Source = new Uri("https://google.com");
  ```
- **Expose an async Initialize method, and await call it when you need**

  If you need to call the [EnsureCoreWebView2Async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.ensurecorewebview2async?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1462.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), you can expose an async method which does the initializations and await call it when you need it.  For example:

  Define the following method for your control:

  ```
   public async Task InitializeControl(string url)
   {
       await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
       webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://google.com");
   }
  ```

  Then use it like this, when you want to initialize it:

  ```
   private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       await myControl.InitializeControl("https://www.google.com");
   }
  ```

- **Call EnsureCoreWebView2Async without await, then do rest of initializations in the event handler ofCoreWebView2InitializationCompleted event**

  You can call the EnsureCoreWebView2Async without await, then you can just do the initialization in the [CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.corewebview2initializationcompleted?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1462.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event handler. For example:

  ```
   webView21.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += (obj, args) =>
   {
       webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://google.com");
   };
   webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
  ```

More information and references:

- [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1462.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235): A good overview of initialization of the control.
- [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.source?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1462.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235): An overview of the Source property.
- [EnsureCoreWebView2Async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.ensurecorewebview2async?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1462.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235): Considerations when calling EnsureCoreWebView2Async method.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that the code must be run on a UI thread (specifically, the UI thread that created the control). This is common for UI COM components.

The code you posted is using `Task.Run` to execute the code on a thread pool thread. To run it on the UI thread instead, remove the `Task.Run`.